# Retry a callback function n times until success

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to make a function to retry calling callback n times until it return TRUE;

Here's my current code:

```
function RetryX(callback, delay, retries) {

    (function wait() {

        if( callback() !== true && --retries > 0 ){
            setTimeout(wait, delay);
        }

    }());

}
```

Question:

1. Is it correct way to do it?
2. Is there any way to optimize it?
3. Can it be modified to pass jslint? currently it shows "unexpected --retries"

Answer (score 3):

Super short review;

- Pure nitpicking, but to me, you try the first time, and retry afterward. This means that a retry of 3 would guarantee up to 4 calls.
- I would not create `wait` but just call the `retryX` function
- JavaScript is lowerCamelCase so `RetryX` -> `retryX`, personally I would go for `tryN`

So probably I would run something like this;

```js
function tryN(callback, delay, tries) {
  
  if(tries && callback() !== true){
    setTimeout(tryN.bind(this, callback, delay, tries-1), delay);
  }
}

function NI(){
 console.log("NI!");
 return false;
}


tryN(NI, 1000, 3);
```

To be clear, if a funny coder passes -1 to this function then you are in an infinite try. Guard for this if you see the need.

Answer (score -1):

### Promise to poll.

Best to poll for state using a promise. As it provides syntax for errors (timeouts) , chained polling queries using `async / await` and more.

### Example

The code below shows the most basic example.

- `poll(call, delay, timeout)` returns a promise to poll `call` every `delay` ms until `timeout` ms have passed. If it times out the promise is rejected.
- `waitForIt` is an async example that waits for a random true.
- `pollingFunc` Is called once every delay and shows the current time elapsed, and returns a random bool state (true or false)
- Last bit of code starts the polling and handles the results when and if ready.
- The example passes the time around. This is just for the example and not required.

```js
function poll(call, delay, timeout) {
    return new Promise((done, timedOut) => {
        const start = performance.now();
        const tick = () => {
            const t = performance.now() - start;
            if (call(t)) { done(t) }
            else if (t > timeout) { timedOut(t); }
            else { setTimeout(tick, delay); }
        };
        tick();
    });
}
const pollingFunc = (time) => {
    console.log("Polling: " + time.toFixed(0) + "ms");
    return Math.random() < 0.05;
}    
async function waitForIt() {
    return poll(pollingFunc , 200, 2000);
}
waitForIt()
  .then(t => console.log("Completed in: " + t.toFixed(0) + "ms"))
  .catch(t => console.log("Error Timed-out: " + t.toFixed(0) + "ms"));

// Or just 
/*
poll(pollingFunc , 200, 2000)
  .then(t => console.log("Completed in: " + t.toFixed(0) + "ms"))
  .catch(t => console.log("Error Timed-out: " + t.toFixed(0) + "ms"));
*/
```